# Any expo react-native AR package?

Tags: react-native, expo, augmented-reality

I'm trying to make an AR app with React-Native with Expo Custom Development Builds, but I can't find any working packages! Any suggestion, help or idea?

Answer (score 1):

[Viro](https://viro-community.readme.io/docs/integrating-with-expo) now provides integration with Expo

Answer (score 0):

Expo **had** an official module called **"Expo-Three-AR"** which was used to build AR applications without ejecting from Expo. This module was built on top of Three.js, and it provided a simple API for working with AR features like planes, anchors, and hit testing.

**However This package is no longer supported as Expo Go's built-in AR support is no longer supported.**

On my personal project, a few weeks ago, I was using **expo-three-ar**, but this library was a **side-project of a dev and should not be considered production ready**

You can read more about it on [Expo-Three-AR github repo](https://github.com/expo/expo-three-ar#readme).